# Recursive query in PostgreSQL. SELECT *

Tags: postgresql, recursion

I have recursive query to retrieve all children of a given person

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM recursetree;
```

As you can see, I'm specifying list of columns to be retrieved. But I want to use `SELECT *` (I have really many columns in real table, and they can be changed in future). Is there some way to get ALL columns without defining each column individually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to specify the columns in the `WITH` part. If you leave that out, the column names will be determined by the first query in the `UNION`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree AS (
    SELECT * FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION
    SELECT t.*
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM recursetree;
```

Comment: Yours is cleaner! I don't know if the intermediate CTE object being "fatter" will affect performance, (I'm afraid it will)

Comment: @wildplasser: only an `explain (analyze, verbose)` can tell ;)

Comment: But I am too lazy to set up a test rig. I'd have to type in all the column names! http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/recursion.html

Comment: I just checked. My intuition was right. 100K rows(22columns, rowsize ~650) ; mine: 439.704ms, yours: 15984.338ms

Answer (score 7):

quick hack-around (rejoin with the original):

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursetree(id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id FROM tree WHERE parent_id = 0
  UNION
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
    FROM tree t
    JOIN recursetree rt ON rt.id = t.parent_id
  )
SELECT *
FROM tree tr
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
    FROM recursetree x
    WHERE x.id = tr.id
    );
```