# Recursive query for hirarchical data based on adjacency list

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Learing SQL, and have a bit of a problem. I have 2 tables `level` and `level_hierarchy`

```
|name        | id |     |parent_id | child_id|
-------------------     ---------------------
| Level1_a   | 1  |     | NULL     |    1    |
| Level2_a   | 19 |     | 1        |    19   |
| Level2_b   | 3  |     | 1        |    3    |
| Level3_a   | 4  |     | 3        |    4    |
| Level3_b   | 5  |     | 3        |    5    | 
| Level4_a   | 6  |     | 5        |    6    | 
| Level4_b   | 7  |     | 5        |    7    |
```

Now what I need, is a query that will return all entries from table `level` from every hirarchy level based on parameter that marks what level hierarchy level I want to get entries from.

Getting `Level1` entries is quite easy.

```
SELECT name FROM level INNER JOIN level_hierarchy ON level.id = 
level_hierarchy.child_id WHERE level_hierarchy.parent_id=NULL
```

`Level2` entries:

```
Level2_a
Level2_b
```

are just the ones that have a parent and the parent of their parent is `NULL` and so on. This is where I suspect that recursion comes in.

Is there anyone who can guide thorugh it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query for the first level (here `depth` to distinguish from the table) should look like this:

```
select l.name, h.child_id, 1 as depth 
from level l
join level_hierarchy h on l.id = h.child_id 
where h.parent_id is null;

   name   | child_id | depth 
----------+----------+-------
 Level1_a |        1 |     1
(1 row)
```

Note the proper use of `is null` (do not use `=` to compare with `null` as it always gives `null`).

You can use the above as an initial query in a recursive cte:

```
with recursive recursive_query as (
    select l.name, h.child_id, 1 as depth 
    from level l
    join level_hierarchy h on l.id = h.child_id 
    where h.parent_id is null
union all
    select l.name, h.child_id, depth + 1
    from level l
    join level_hierarchy h on l.id = h.child_id
    join recursive_query r on h.parent_id = r.child_id
)
select *
from recursive_query
-- where depth = 2

   name   | child_id | depth 
----------+----------+-------
 Level1_a |        1 |     1
 Level2_b |        3 |     2
 Level2_a |       19 |     2
 Level3_a |        4 |     3
 Level3_b |        5 |     3
 Level4_a |        6 |     4
 Level4_b |        7 |     4
(7 rows)
```

Comment: I like the depth field, that really makes things clear!

Comment: Please how do I modify this to get all the parents of child given the child's id ?

Comment: @YemiKudaisi - see [Recursive CTE concatenate fields with parents from arbitrary point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530450/1995738)

Answer (score 3):

Good question, recursion is a difficult topic in SQL and its implementation varies by engine.  Thanks for tagging your post with PostgreSQL.  PostgreSQL has some excellent [documentation on the topic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html).

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec_lh(child_id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT child_id, parent_id FROM level_hierarchy
  UNION ALL
    SELECT lh.child_id, lh.parent_id
    FROM rec_lh rlh INNER JOIN level_hierarchy lh
      ON lh.parent_id = rlh.child_id
  )
SELECT DISTINCT level.name, child_id 
FROM rec_lh INNER JOIN level
  ON rec_lh.parent_id = level.id
ORDER BY level.name ASC;
```

**See Also:**

[Recursive query in PostgreSQL. SELECT *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943766/recursive-query-in-postgresql-select)