# Postgres get root of self-referential table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE self-ref (
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  parent VARCHAR REFERENCES self-ref(name),

  PRIMARY KEY(name)
);
```

If I get a name from the table (and thus the Pkey), how can I get the name of it's "root"-level parent: the name where parent is NULL which is referenced to (indirectly) by the given name.

Say I have these values (I don't know which values I will get):

```
+-------------+-----------+
| Name        | Parent    |
+-------------+-----------+
| Root 1      | NULL      |
| Root 2      | NULL      |
| Child 1     | Root 1    |
| Child 2     | Root 2    |
| Sub-child 1 | Child 1   |
+-------------+-----------+
```

The function/whatever solution should return *Root 1* for *Root 1*, *Child 1* and *Sub-child 1*; and should return *Root 2* for *Root 2* and *Child 2*.

How can I achieve this?
*Note:* It really has to be Postgres....

Comment: You need a recursive hierarchical query to handle this requirement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen could explain a bit more, please? (Edit: I'm not quite used to this kind of puzzles to solve ...)

Comment: See [Recursive CTE concatenate fields with parents from arbitrary point.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530450/1995738)

Comment: Thank you @klin. How to compare the result of this query (a table-like structure) to a single VARCHAR value? As in, I need to if the value is 'inherited' from a certain root.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a closure table - like I did (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802) Closure table allows a lot of freedom in your queries - but of course takes additional space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE.  The syntax looks like:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select name, name as parent
      from selfref
      where parent is null
      union all
      select s.name, cte.parent
      from cte join
           selfref s
           on s.parent = cte.name
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=678eb694a8aa363eb109937d2ebfeafb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Is it possible to have the CTE exclude (null) the anchor result of the query?